# Как при нажатии на кнопку удалять текст в canvas и выводить новый (на том же месте)?

Tags: python, canvas, текст

Проблема: При нажатии на кнопку выводит текст: 'Вход выполнен.', но при вводе других данных выводит уже другой текст: 'Ошибка авторизации!', который наслаивается на 'Вход выполнен.'

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image


def Doctype():
    text_id1=my_canvas.create_text(370,500, text='Вход выполнен.', fill='Green', font='Verdana 30')


def Error():
    text_id2=my_canvas.create_text(350,500, text='Ошибка авторизации!', fill='Red', font='Verdana 30')


def Getinfo():
    name=name_entry.get()
    password=pass_entry.get()
    if name==password:
            return Doctype()
    else:
        return Error()


root = Tk()
root.title('Авторизация')
root.geometry("1300x900")

#Canvas
my_canvas = Canvas(root, width=323, height=576, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
my_canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
root.resizable(width=True, height=True)


my_canvas.create_text(370,200, text='Пользователь', fill='Black', font='Verdana 22')
my_canvas.create_text(420,300, text='Пароль', fill='Black', font='Verdana 22')


name_entry = Entry(root, font=("Helvetica", 18), width=13, fg='Black', bg='White')
name_window = my_canvas.create_window(500, 190, anchor="nw", window=name_entry)

pass_entry = Entry(root, font=("Helvetica", 18), width=13, fg='Black', bg='White')
pass_window = my_canvas.create_window(500, 290, anchor="nw", window=pass_entry)


btn = Button(root, text='Вход', font='Helvetica 18', width=10, bg='White', fg='Black', command=Getinfo)
btn_window = my_canvas.create_window(420,370, anchor='nw', window=btn)


root.mainloop()
```

[image: Наслоение]

[image: Выполнен]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас при каждом вызове функции создается новый текстовый объект на `Canvas`. Лучше его создать заранее с пустым содержимым, а затем в функциях `Doctype` и `Error` просто менять текст на нужный `my_canvas.itemconfig(text_id, text='Нужный текст!')`.
И не забудьте добавить: `text_id = my_canvas.create_text(350, 500, text='', fill='Red', font='Verdana 30')`.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image


def Doctype():
    my_canvas.itemconfig(text_id, text='Вход выполнен.')


def Error():
    my_canvas.itemconfig(text_id, text='Ошибка авторизации!')


def Getinfo():
    name = name_entry.get()
    password = pass_entry.get()
    if name == password:
        return Doctype()
    else:
        return Error()


root = Tk()
root.title('Авторизация')
root.geometry("1300x900")

# Canvas
my_canvas = Canvas(root, width=323, height=576, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
my_canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
text_id = my_canvas.create_text(350, 500, text='', fill='Red', font='Verdana 30')
root.resizable(width=True, height=True)

my_canvas.create_text(370, 200, text='Пользователь', fill='Black', font='Verdana 22')
my_canvas.create_text(420, 300, text='Пароль', fill='Black', font='Verdana 22')

name_entry = Entry(root, font=("Helvetica", 18), width=13, fg='Black', bg='White')
name_window = my_canvas.create_window(500, 190, anchor="nw", window=name_entry)

pass_entry = Entry(root, font=("Helvetica", 18), width=13, fg='Black', bg='White')
pass_window = my_canvas.create_window(500, 290, anchor="nw", window=pass_entry)

btn = Button(root, text='Вход', font='Helvetica 18', width=10, bg='White', fg='Black', command=Getinfo)
btn_window = my_canvas.create_window(420, 370, anchor='nw', window=btn)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Comment: @Kennedy вашу правку-дополнение стоило дописать комментарием, а автор ответа возможно сам бы внес ее в ответ, если согласен. Вообще, не понятно зачем это, в коде эта строка есть, возможно стоило бы ее как-то выделить.

Comment: @insolor мб, просто чё-то затупил, не понимая что за text_id появился. Кому то поможет разобраться.